# Windows 7 working on minimum requirements

Tags: windows-7

I have several computer on my school that I'm working on. There's several computer with Windows XP still installed. I would like to make the best of this situation.

Some of them have 2GB RAM and a reasonable processor. I would like to install Windows 7 but the problem is:  There's plenty of services that we don't use that will consume resources that we desperately need. Is there a way I can get a version of Windows 7 with minimum services running? Just services like Networking.

Hope I could be clear enough.

Comment: Then disable those services in Windows Services. See this page on how to configure windows services...http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various tutorials on how to do this. You should look out for tutorials concerned with virtual machines (because there you also want to save RAM and HDD space). Also, tutorials that deal with Netbooks or small SSDs are usefull.

There is also a nice GUI to create a shrinked installation medium: https://www.ntlite.com/

A nice tutorial is this one:
https://www.ntlite.com/discussions/#/discussion/246/tutorial-for-creating-a-700mb-windows-7-or-8-iso-and-install-in-a-vm

Other tools are:

- http://www.rt7lite.com/
- http://www.wincert.net/forum/files/file/5-win-toolkit/

Comment: Download links on the rt7lite page are broken.

Comment: Indeed it is. Looks like the project is no longer maintained. If you still want to try it, just do a google search. It is available from many pc-magazine websites.